# jQuery Overlay from within a function

Tags: .net, jquery, html, css

i am out of my depth but trying my best to learn as I go. Any help is appreciated.
I am trying to give a face lift to an outdated site while being as non-invasive as possible.

most of the form elements and buttons are being created with .NET controls so I cant change or rename them otherwise the page returns an error.

the submit button has "onclick=validate(this.form)" which checks that the form elements are not blank and then returns true if all is good.

I would like to use jQuery Overlay from within this function but am not sure how to go about doing so, could someone help me?

I was thinking something like:

```
function validate(t){
...
if (t.Phone3.value == "")
{
alert("Please enter Phone Number. Thank you.");
t.Phone3.focus();
return (false);
}
else
{
$("#prompt").overlay();
}
```

then within the div id="prompt" I would have a button which returns true and one that just closes the modal returning false

this doesnt seem to work though as the modal is not popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any JavaScript errors on the page? If it's not a JavaScript error, it's possible that ASP.NET is creating a lot of complicated markup that could be interfering with the CSS/HTML that jQuery Overlay is trying to use to make the modal popup.

Comment: this ASP.NET coding is killing me. It ties my hands at every step.

Comment: The previous programmer has all of the form elements, even the buttons, being generated by .NET.